# What is the probability that $X$ is located closer to $Y$ than to $0$?

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution

X and Y are uniform random variables.
X uniformly distributed on $[0, \frac{L}{2}]$ and Y is uniformly distibuted on $[\frac{L}{2}, L]$.

What is the probability that $X$ is located closer to $Y$ than to $0\,?$
$$$$
My attempt (which haven't got too far):

I am looking for the set of all points ${\{(x,y)\;|\;\;y-x<x,\;0\le x \le \frac{L}{2}, \; \frac{L}{2}\le y \le L  \}}$ out of ${\{(x,y)\;|\;\;\;0\le x \le \frac{L}{2}, \; \frac{L}{2}\le y \le L  \}}$. Thus:

$P(Y-X<X) = P(Y-2X<0)=$ Well i'm not sure how to continue from here.

What is the simpliest way of solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is correct but you need to complete the proof. Consider the set of all points $(X,Y)$ satisfying your conditions. All the points must satisfy the conditions $0\le X\le R$, $R\le Y\le 1$ where $R$ is $L/2$ a fixed number between $0, 1$. So the set of all points you consider is a rectangle $U$ of height $1-R$ and width $R$, area $A=R-R^2$.

The subset you are interested in is the set $S$ of points $(X,Y)$ such that $X>Y-X$ or $Y<2X$. So $S$ consists of all points from $U$ under the line $Y=2X$. The area $A_S$ of $S$ depends on $R$ and can be easily found. Indeed, let, say $R=2/3$. Then $S$ is a trapezium with height $1-R=1/3$, and bases $R-R/2=1/3$ and $R-1/2=1/6$, so $A_S=1/2(1/3+1/6)1/3=1/12$. Then the probability is $A_S/A$ (in the above case when $R=2/3$, the probability is $(1/12)/(2/3-4/9)=9/24=3/8$).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer!
Just one little thing... I accidently wrote $1$ instead of $L$. Meaning that $X$~$[0,\frac{L}{2}]$ and $Y$~$[\frac{L}{2}, L]$.
Sorry for the inaccuracy.
Does this changes your answer?

Comment: It makes the answer simpler. The area $A$ of the rectangle is  $2R^2$ where $R=L/2$. The region $S$ is a trapezium of height $R$, and bases $2R-R/2=3R/2$ and $2R-R=R$, so the area $A_S=1/2R(5/2R)=(5/4)R^2$ and the probability is $(5/4)R^2/(2R^2)=5/8$, does not depend on $L$.

Comment: I have another thought. Thanks to your direction, i tried to look at the graph of $y-2x<0$ with GeoGebra in the area $A$. Since the answer doesn't really depend on $L$, let's just say that $L=4$, so $X$~$[0,2]$ and $Y$~$[2,4]$. I drew the square of the area $A$ and added the restriction of $y-2x<0$. The way i see it, the region $S$ (what we are looking for) is a triangular of hight $\frac{L}{2}=\frac{4}{2}=2$ and base of $\frac{L}{4}=\frac{4}{4}=1$, thus it's area is $\frac{1*2}{2}=1$. And since the area of $A$ is $\frac{L}{2}*\frac{L}{2}=2*2=4$, the answer should be $\frac{1}{4}$. Am i right?

Comment: here's my draw:
https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/p43w5jr5

Comment: It could be that $S$ is in fact a triangle and your computation  is correct.